# Схема mongoose (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Совсем что то запутался, может кто то поможет в реализации.
Написал схему

```
var schema = new Schema({
    vehicle: {
        name:   { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        url:    { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
    },
    models: [{
        model: {
            name: { type: String },
            subname: { type: Array }
        }
    }],
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Но нужно немного не то.

Не пойму как правильно расставить все по полочкам.
Есть каталог автомобилей к примеру Mercedes
vehicle.name: Mercedes

Далее нужно в models записать все модели Mercedes рассортировать их по классам, т.е.:

```
Класс А = array(
    name: '180',
    name: '200',
    name: '220',

);
```

Или как то по другому сделать, чтобы при выборке Класса А получить список автомобилей этого класса.

Может в данном случае будет правильнее завести отдельную коллекцию с модельным рядом автомобилей принадлежащих этому классу?

Comment: по-моему проще для каждой модели указать отдельным полем класс, т.е. как-то так:

    models:[{name:"W140",class:"S-class"},{name:"C215",class:"CL-class"},...]

или вы какой-то другой каталог подразумеваете? Просто через map-reduce вы сможете получить в итоге любую группировку и любой фильтр и так...

Comment: Да да, я об этом даже не подумал, просто уже в голове все перемешалось. Так наверное будет более правильно. Спасибо.
Но, может кто то еще что посоветует дельно =) Будет интересно вобщем!